# Não é possível validar "undefined" - JS

Tags: javascript

Tenho um objeto, onde em algumas requisições o mesmo retorna sem determinados valores.

O problema, que ao tentar validar os valores, o mesmo gera erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: Ao analisar, percebi a seguinte situação:

**Código:**

```
var a = {f : 1}
console.log(a) //{f: "Olha"}
console.log(a.b) //undefined
console.log(a.b.c) //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined at window.onload
```

O grande problema é saber se o valor anterior não foi definido. Por ser uma API de terceiros, não sei se quais valores podem vir setados.

Como faço para validar neste tipo de situação?

**Jsfiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/o5w1nd2L/

Comment: Aparentemente seu erro reporta não existir ou estar "nula" a propriedade `speed`... considere adicionar em sua pergunta a parte relevante do código em questão desta forma será mais provável que você de fato obtenha uma resposta satisfatória.

Answer (score 2):

Seguindo seu exmplo:

```
var a = {f : 1}
console.log(a)     // output: {f:1}
console.log(a.b)   // output: undefined
console.log(a.b.c) // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined
```

Isto ocorre porque **"b"** não existe (`undefined`) logo **"c"** não pode ser uma propriedade... por isso a `VM` do `javascript` lançara um `Error`.

Para verificar se uma dada propriedade existe em um `{Object}` usando a instrução `if` você podes usar o operador [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).

**exemplo**:

```
var a = {f : 1}
//
if ('b' in a) {
    console.log(a.b)
}
if ('b' in a && 'c' in a.b) {
    console.log(a.b.c)
}
```

Dentro de um bloco subsequente você poderia também utilizar da seguinte maneira:

```
var a = {f : 1}
//
if ('b' in a) {
    // assumindo que existe a propriedade "b" no objeto "a"...
    if ('c' in a.b) {
        console.log(a.b.c)
    }
}
```

Se você não pode "saber" se o objeto terá ou não todas as propriedades más sabe que o objeto deve ter um "padrão" talvez o mais indicado seria iterar sobre este objeto.